# can I add new property when create new doc in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this schema (for example):

```
var WordSchema = new Schema({
    word: {
        type: String
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Word', WordSchema);
```

How I can add new property when create new doc in mongoose? something like this:

```
let Word = require("../models/word");
let initWord = "hello";
word = new Word({
   word: initWord,
   length: initWord.length
});

word.save(function(error) {
  if (error) {  
    //some code              
  } else {
    //some code              
  }
});
```

But this does not work

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here.  Do you want to know how to add additional fields to a mongoose document that are then SAVED to the database?

Comment: I think it's clear, I have a schema with 1 property, now I want to create and save an document with 2 property.
but I want to add the second property when I am creating new of schema

Comment: I might help you if I understood what you were asking :)

Comment: Yes, I know and thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Mongoose doesn't allow you to dynamically add fields to your document.

But, if you create the schema with the strict option set to false,  you can:

```
var WordSchema = new Schema({
word: {
    type: String
}
}, {strict: false});
```

In order to get at a property that's not in the schema you need to use a special getter form:

```
doc.get('length')
```

Or convert the document into a plain old javascript object by calling:

```
doc.toObject()
```

on the retrieved schema object.